# How can I add and subtract items by pressing a button?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am coding a store site in which I put two buttons to add and subtract items in the shopping cart. When the number of goods is several, the buttons work correctly, but if the number of goods is one, the buttons do not work, and by executing a new operation, the previous command of the buttons works. I think I should use the useEffect [Here you can see a photo of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Kcv.png)hook, but I don't know how. Please help me. I have also uploaded a photo of my code.

Comment: You should try using concat and filter to update state immutably.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to show off your code, use triple back ticks instead e.g. "```"